# App in Angular 2 stuck in Loading

Tags: angular

I have been trying to run the app with npm start and to show the Html code I put in the template but doesn't work.
My system setup is the following:

[image: ![Project Structure]

app.component.ts:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Display something</h1>' // <------
    })
    export class AppComponent {}
```

app.module.ts

```
   import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser'
   import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
   import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms';
   import { HttpModule }       from '@angular/http';

   import { AppComponent }     from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

main.ts the same as the Angular 2 Quickstart

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

index.html extracted from the angular 2 Quickstart

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/   ">
    <title>Proof of Concept v 0.0.2</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Checking the browser console I see the following error:
[image: Browser console error]

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any errors? From my experience, Angular is pretty good at spitting out informative error messages.

Comment: I have checked it the error is the following: http://imgur.com/AfHu8Dsl.png some problem with zone.js which I don't really know what is it

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you missed to properly configure System loader i.e. System.config

have a look how it is configured inside systemjs.config.js 
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

you can also have a look at systemjs config documentation
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

Comment: I am using exactly the same configuration

Comment: you are not using it as it is explained in the tutorial.
have a look at systemjs.config.js
you have to tell the systemjs to start from your main.js file
and you are also missing the mapping of your app folder.